# Are these sentences grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, compound-sentences

Are these sentences grammatically correct? If not then kindly explain.

1. I was wondering if you have ever used our online services.
2. I was wondering if you used/had used our online services.
3. I thought you wanted to go to the party.
4. I thought you want to go to the party.
5. I thought life always gives us a second chance.
6. I thought life always gave us a second chance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. "I was wondering if you used our online services" is correct. I was wondering if you had used our online services" could be correct in context, but probably you want to say "I was wondering if you have used our online services."
3. Yes
4. No. "Wanted" is the same form as "thought." You could say "I think you want to go to the party."
5. No. Same reason as 4. One could say "I think life always gives us a second chance."
6. Yes.